Is there a way to specify the zone_redundant flag for an Event Hub since this flag has been deprecated in azurerm 4.0?
We have been using Terraform to instantiate an Event Hub with the zone_redundant flag set to true, and have been seeing the message:
The `zone_redundant` property has been deprecated and will be removed in v4.0 of the provider.

V4.0 has now been released and as promised that flag is no longer accepted.  However, when we talked to our Microsoft reps they were unaware of that flag being deprecated in Azure and it is still a setting in the Azure Portal UI.  Therefore, I am looking to answer the following questions.  If this flag is indeed unnecessary, I would like to see documentation of this fact as I checked and simply removing it from the TF does not set it, i.e., it does not default to "true".  I had found some references that implied that this might be the case but they did not pan out.  Otherwise, assuming that the flag is not a noop, we do want it set and are at a loss as to how to adjust our Terraform script to have the desired effect.
Two things.  First, leaving the flag in as above we got the error documented above which as of release 4.0 is fatal.  Similarly running with the flag missing we confirmed that the Event Hub it created did not have this property (wanted to check if it defaulted to on).

You would need to consult the API docs i.e. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/eventhub/ for interfacing deprecations. The UI is not necessarily representative.

I saw this too... Why would they remove something it's still used? It would be good to now why something was removed.......


Adding zone redundance enabled to EventHub's explicitly using terraform

You are right the zone redundance was depreciating as per the latest terraform documentation there is not property mentioned zone redundant was available which means they removed it.

How ever If you're newly creating an EventHub with zone redundant available we can achieve this using CLI commands and include those in null resource terraform.
I was mentioning this even we have the module to create on using terraform because once the EventHub gets created we cannot update its zone redundance parameter & also as per MSDoc we have a selected list of regions where zone redundant property enabled and works as expected.
Configuration:
provider "azurerm" {
  features {} 
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "vinay-rg"
  location = "eastus2"
}

resource "null_resource" "create_eventhub_namespace" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<EOT
      az eventhubs namespace create --resource-group ${azurerm_resource_group.example.name} --name vinay-eventhubns --location ${azurerm_resource_group.example.location} --sku Standard --capacity 1 --zone-redundant true
    EOT
    interpreter = ["pwsh", "-c"]
  }

  depends_on = [azurerm_resource_group.example]
}


Deployment:


Refer:
Azure Service Bus and Azure Event Hubs expand availability | Microsoft Azure Blog
azurerm_eventhub_namespace | Resources | hashicorp/azurerm | Terraform | Terraform Registry
